# problem with saving matlab graphics as SVG: SVG file has incorrect axes length

Tags: matlab, svg, plot

I have a problem with saving a Matlab figure as ".svg" and subsequently opening it in Inkscape. More precisely, I need two subplots to be a specific height, i.e. 6cm. This can be done in Matlab by setting the "Position" property (and setting the units to "centimeters"). This all works as expected and I then export the figure as ".svg"

The problem is that when I import the figure to Inkscape the axes length is close to the value I set but not correct. I.e. I set it to 6 cm and it is 6.28 in Inkscape. It is not much of an error, but it completely defeats the purpose of defining it in the first place. Any ideas?

I tried exporting the figure in several different ways but the result is always the same.

```
figure('name','representative plasticity figure');
set(gcf,'Color','w','units','centimeters','position',...
[0 0 8.6 8.4],'PaperPositionMode','auto'); 
s1=subplot(2,1,1)
img = imagesc(magic(8)); hold on; 
set(gca, 'TickDir','out','FontSize',8.5,'LineWidth',0.59,'TickLength'...
,[0.03 0.00001]); 
c1 = colorbar; c1.Box = 'off';c1.TickDirection = 'out'; c1.FontSize = 8.5; 

ax1 = gca; ax1.Units = 'Centimeters';ax1.Position(3:4) = [3.427, 1.59]; 
box off;  % THIS IS THE SIZE I NEED BUT WHICH ISN'T PRINTED CORRECTLY

c1.Label.String = '[whatever]';
subplot(2,1,2)
p1=plot(randi(5,5),'r','LineWidth',0.64); hold on; 
box off; set(gca, 'TickDir','out','TickLength',...
[0.03 0.00001],'FontSize',8.5,'LineWidth',0.64);% legend('pre','post'); 
legend('boxoff');
ax2 = gca;ax2.Units = 'Centimeters';ax2.Position(3:4) = ax1.Position(3:4); 
xlabel ('whatever' ); ylabel('whatever');
print myplot -dsvg
```

The size of the figure should be [3.427, 1.59] in cm. And it is so in the resulting matlab figure, however, in Inkscape it is more like 3.6 and 1.7.

Comment: You need to use `PaperPosition`, `PaperUnits` etc to set the size of figures when saved to file. `Position` is for screen position.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In my hands that doesn't solve it either. There is still a tiny but significant difference in figure size. I think it may have to do with default DPI settings which may differ between Matlab and Inkscape, but I can't figure out what I need to adjust.